# Next js - css cache?

Tags: javascript, css, sass, next.js

Im using Next.js (12.1.0) with SCSS modules, and my CSS is caching so hard, that I have to restart the next (npm run next dev) to clear it. How do you guys get rid off this? Any way to no cache at all? Or what am I doing wrong?

Comment: does browser hard reload work

Comment: nope, nor incognito or anything, its next cache

Comment: Can you provide a [mre]?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This happens because of a minor error in css/scss file naming.

In case if you imported the css file as:

`import styles from '../styles/component.module.css'`
Better change it to: 
`import styles from '../styles/Component.module.css'`

Make sure you are using class naming style to name Component.module.css file with the first letter being uppercase. This will solve the issue.
Cheers!